# Definition of divergence of a tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

How do you formally define the divergence of an arbitrary $(p,q)$ tensor? And what does it geometrically signify?

Answer (score 3):

If $T$ is a $(p,q)$ tensor then the divergence $\delta T$ is $$\delta T := 
\mathbb{tr} \big(X \mapsto \nabla_X T\big),$$ that is to say the divergence is the trace of 
the map sending a vector field $X$ to the covariant derivative of $T$ w.r.t $X$. Thus $\delta T$ is a $(p-1,q)$ tensor. Here I am assuming that the tensor $T$ lives on a smooth manifold equipped with a linear connection.

The geometric intuition usually comes from Physics via Stokes' theorem, e.g. $\delta T$ integrates to zero over a compact manifold.

Comment: Thank for your good answer. I have a question: how to calculate $div(T)S(X)$ where $T,S$ are $(1,1)$-tensor in terms of $div(ToS)$?